# Does Android Bluetooth API will discover all the version of Bluetooth device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Is Android Device will discover all type of Bluetooth version device? Is Android Bluetooth APIs will connect to all Bluetooth device(All version like v2.1, v3.0 and v4.0)?

Comment: I think this depends on the hardware I know that Bluetooth 4.0 is not supported for my device because is too old. But wait, I don't know Bluetooth 2.1 are you talking about Android or Bluetooth versions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am sure that **Android device of O.S version (All version like v2.1, v3.0 and v4.0)**  **DISCOVER** and even **CONNECT** to the other Bluetooth devices. I am saying all this because I am experienced  with these features.

**Edited**: You can take help from [Bluetooth Chat app](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

Comment: Asking that Android will connect to these version like v2.1, v3.0 and v4.0 of Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Thought you denoting android version? Ok, you have any document for this?